# How to make custom graphql query with parameters?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

On laravel site with lighthouse I need to make custom query with some filters and some output
fields formatted in custom way

Checking all lighthouse commands :

```
php artisan lighthouse
```

I create custom query :

```
php artisan lighthouse:query Items
```

But I am not sure how have I to change graphql file and query request? In file graphql/item.graphql I changed :

```
extend type Query {
# I suppose that to remove @paginate directive
#    items [Item!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 10)
items: [Item!]
```

and query request string:

```
{
  items (filterByStatus: 'a' ) {
    id
    name
   }
}
```

But in graphql-playground I do not see any errors/messages and no logs activity on laravel side.

Which way is valid and how can I debug such issue ?

As with query request string above graphql-playground does does not triggered at all, but it works ok :

```
{
  items  {
    id
    name
   }
}

"laravel/framework": "^9.48.0",
"nuwave/lighthouse": "^6.6"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if your schema is correct and valid, use the command:
`php artisan lighthouse:validate-schema`. See in lighthouse [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/commands.html#scalar) more info.

To add that filter `filterByStatus`, you need to change your query file `graphql/item.graphql`.

```
extend type Query {
    items(
        filterByStatus: String @where(key: "status", operator: "like") #I assume is string by the 'a', your key on BD is status and operadtor is like. You can use other directives like @in, @whereIn, @whereKey etc..
    ): [Item!]
}
```

All lighthouse directives are in [here](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/directives.html#wherekey). If you want to explore more, on lighthouse [usage](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/the-basics/directives.html#usage), you have a general example of a query with filters.